# discriminating whether python object is subclass of current __init__ method

Tags: python, init

This is an odd one.  I have run into a situation a few times where I would like to do some action at the end of `__init__` of a python object.  I would like to do the action as the last thing in the `__init__` of the true class (leaf class) only.  I absolutely do not want to do it if in a superclass of self `__init__` method.  Is there a good way to do this?  I grant it may be a silly thing to do.  But it has me curious whether and how it could be done.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you just saying that you want each leaf class to be able to do the superclass stuff and then do its own stuff afterward (without its own stuff being done for instances of the superclass)? Or are you trying to detect programmatically whether a class is a leaf class, so you can have a single method that does different things in the two cases? Or…?

Comment: The case at hand is one of an ORM wanting to store new instance of subclasses of PersistentObject automatically.  I know of [many] other ways to make this particular use case work but I was curious about a possible solution that could discriminate in the __init__ itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you want some code to run in the leaf class, at the end of `__init__`, without it running in the base class… just override `__init__` in the leaf class. For example:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Base initializing')
class Intermediate(Base):
    pass
class Leaf(Intermediate):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Leaf, self).__init__()
        print('Leaf initializing')

>>> o = Base()
Base initializing
>>> o = Intermediate()
Base initializing
>>> o = Leaf()
Base initializing
Leaf initializing
```

---

If you're trying to programmatically detect, from within a method like `Base.__init__`, whether `self` is a `Base` or some subclass of `Base`… well, usually this is a bad idea, and you actually want to use method overriding, as above. But it can be done easily. For example:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if type(self) != Base:
            print('Some subclass of Base initializing')
class Leaf(Base):
    pass

>>> obj = Leaf()
Some subclass of Base initializing
```

(If you're worried that someone might subvert your hierarchy such that some object that's neither a `Base` *nor* a subclass of it might end up calling `Base.__init__`, and you're sure that would be an evil thing rather than a clever monkeypatching thing, you can always check `issubclass`.)

---

If you're trying to programmatically detect, within a method like `Base.__init__`, whether base is a "real class"… well, you need to define what that means. Does it mean "Not an abstract base class in the PEP3119 sense"? "Has no subclasses defined (yet)"? "Has an implementation for some critical method"? Whatever you want to do is probably doable, but some will be harder than others. (For example, to detect whether anyone has subclassed your class, you'll likely need to build a custom metaclass.)

Comment: Clearly the distinction between "evil" and "clever monkeypatching" is a fine one...

Comment: @DanielRoseman: There's really no point in trying to stop evil misuse of your code in Python, but a lot of novices still ask for ways to do it, so… I'll let them define evil their own way. Of course their own way is wrong, since you can tell by whether the monkeys live in a secret volcano lair, or in an apartment with a main in a yellow hat, but they will learn that as they get more familiar with Python.

Comment: I was hoping there was something less ugly than putting
if self.__class__ == MyClass:..
or the equivalent everywhere.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins: As I said in the answer, "usually this is a bad idea, and you actually want to use method overriding". In Python, things that are usually a bad idea are often ugly, sometimes intentionally so. If you really want to, you can hide the ugliness in a metaclass or a method or class decorator—which has the advantage of factoring it out so you only have to do it once, too—but if that's what you want, you have to do it _somewhere_ (or do something even uglier, like `sys.getframe`, or more inscrutable, like a defaulted flag parameter).

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't yet figured out how to do the minimal metaclass solution for this but am leaning in that direction.  

For the use case in question I can't just use method override because the goal is to save a never persisted before object to a data store and only after it is finished initializing. So calling the overrode method before the end of the __init__ chain would still miss __init__ created data in the first save.  I can postpone doing that save by storing away the object for later persisting.  But that is letting the language determine when I do the work and seems inelegant.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins: First, it sounds like you're never going to be instantiating the base class directly anyway. So why bother trying to detect whether it's a subclass if it's _always_ a subclass? If you want to _ensure_ that instead of just assuming it, make the base an [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), or make it only work as a mixin.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins: As for the actual problem… what you want is a hook that runs after the most-derived `__init__` finishes, right? The _easy_ way to do this is to invent your own protocol—move the actual construction outside of `__init__`, don't provide an `__init__` method in the derived classes and instead provide something called, say, `__construct__`. Then `Base.__init__` just calls `__construct__`, and then does the rest. If that isn't appropriate, I can explain other possibilities, but again, this is definitely the simplest.

Comment: If all the derived classes and their subclasses provide __construct__ and it is called from the one and only __init__ then this would only work if we didn't need to call any super __construct__ from the leaf class __construct__ which is not the case is any of the intermediate supers need to do init time work.  So this doesn't work.

Comment: Sure it does. Just call `super().__construct__()` from each `__construct__()` method (and put a no-op implementation in the base class). So the base class's `__init__` can do any "pre-initialization", then call `self.__construct__` (which will call the most-derived `__construct__` method, which calls up the chain), then do any "post-initialization", secure in the fact that no "real initialization" has been done before the pre-init code, and all of it has been done before the post-init code.

Comment: Also, if you _really_ want to, you can create a metaclass that lets you write the derived methods (and super calls) as `__init__` but turns them into `__construct__` instead. But I think this would be a bad idea.

Comment: It is not true that I don't instantiate any of the intermediate classes directly.  
If the __construct__ does the save of the object to the data store then the save could be done before some subclass __construct__ is run so a partial new object is saved.  
It still seems like 
if self.__class__ == current_class: self.save_to_store()
is about the best I can do simply.